# Newline is not working with parbox and usebox

Tags: macros, line-breaking, boxes

I would like to save data to a savebox (or any other storage element) in iterations. At the end I would like to put each datapoint in a framebox and then in a frambox container with a given width.
Here is my implementation:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newsavebox{\foo}
\newcommand{\savedata}[1]{\savebox{\foo}{\usebox{\foo} \fbox{#1}}}
\newcommand{\printdata}{\framebox{\parbox{4cm}{\usebox{\foo}}}}
\begin{document}
The desired usage:
\savedata{This is a box}
\savedata{This is another box}
\savedata{This is third box}
\printdata
\\
The desired output:
\framebox{\parbox{4cm}{
  \fbox{This is a box} 
  \fbox{This is another box} 
  \fbox{This is third box}}}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image: Output]
As seen does the container not wrap the inner framebox when using the programmatic implementation. What is wrong?

Comment: you are adding stuff outside a parbox when you are saving. Then everything is locked in place. Add the `\parbox` to the save instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want raggedright to allow the lines to be short and need to unbox the saved data to allow linebreaking:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newsavebox{\foo}
\newcommand{\savedata}[1]{\savebox{\foo}{\ifvoid\foo\else\unhbox\foo{} \fi\fbox{#1}}}
\newcommand{\printdata}{\framebox{\parbox{4cm}{\raggedright\unhbox\foo}}}
\begin{document}
The desired usage:
\savedata{This is a box}
\savedata{This is another box}
\printdata

The desired output:
\framebox{\parbox{4cm}{\raggedright\fbox{This is a box} \fbox{This is another box}}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If the `\savedata` are short words then more boxes occurs at the same line (like words in a paragraph). Is it desired?

Comment: @wipet My guess was that was the intention, and I got the tick so I assume my guess was right:-)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure you want to use boxes:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\cleardata}{\renewcommand*{\saveddata}{}}
\newcommand*\saveddata{} % initialize

\newcommand{\savedata}[1]{%
  \unskip
  \ifx\saveddata\empty
  \else
    \appto{\saveddata}{\\}
  \fi
  \appto{\saveddata}{\fbox{#1}}\ignorespaces
}
\newcommand{\printdata}[1][4cm]{\fbox{\parbox{#1}{\raggedright\saveddata}}}

\begin{document}
The desired usage:
\savedata{This is a box}
\savedata{This is another box}
\savedata{This is third box}
\printdata

The desired output:
\framebox{\parbox{4cm}{
  \fbox{This is a box} \\
  \fbox{This is another box} \\
  \fbox{This is third box}}}

With optional argument: \printdata[6cm]
\end{document}
```

The command `\cleardata` resets the mechanism for adding new boxes.

[image]

Here I used `etoolbox` for convenience. You can avoid it by defining `\appto` yourself:

```
\makeatletter
\providecommand\appto[2]{%
  \ifx#1\@undefined
    \def#1{#2}%
  \else
    \expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I would like to not include any packages. Therefore I prefer boxes.

Comment: @TorsteinI.Bø `etoolbox` is just for convenience. You can dispense with it. I'll add a note.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you need 4cm width of the completed box? Isn't better to set this width as the width of the most wide box inside? If so, then you can use:

```
\newbox\foo
\def\savedata#1{\setbox\foo=\vbox{\unvbox\foo \hbox{\fbox{#1}}\kern1pt}\ignorespaces}
\def\printdata{\framebox{$\vcenter{\box\foo\kern-1pt}$}}
```

Comment: For my case, the width is fixed to the linewidth.

Comment: @TorsteinI.Bø This is impossible. You have the text before box "The desired output:" The width of the box plus the width of this text have to be less than linewidth. And there is ugly white space at the right side in the box.

Comment: I know, but this is a minimal example. So I have done some simplifications.